# How can I set background image when half of app screen slides down for the behavior double tap the home button?

Tags: objective-c, ios8

I'm finding a way to set a background image when half of app screen slides down. for the behaviour double tap the home button. Can anybody give me some help for this?

Comment: For better question I will attach image link. http://goo.gl/si4QHU

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That area is not part of the application, but rather a view placed by the operating system.

Think of the double tap as a mechanism for the OS to "shift" your app down for easier access.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I think apple should provide a way to set a background image for the part. If we can set, we can give users better experience.

Comment: Possibly a nice feature to have for developers, but I think they might want this to be common background across the entire OS. Please accept my answer if you are happy with it. Thanks.

Comment: Thank you. I fully understand your answers.